# Proving every subset of a finite set is finite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subset of a finite set is finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239566/subset-of-a-finite-set-is-finite)

I see this proof is presented using induction here http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Subset_of_Finite_Set_is_Finite

Why do we need to use induction and such a long proof, instead could not we use basic proof by contradiction and let there exist an infinite subset. Then since a set contains its subset it will be infinite too leading to a contradiction.

I am trying to learn proofs and analysis by selfstudy and I don't have professors to help me so can anyone explain me why this proof approach is preferred and is my proof wrong ?

Comment: What's your definition of finite set? What's an infinite set? The proof will depend on the details.

Comment: I would have thought it was "obvious" that a subset of a finite set is finite. How could it have more elements than the original set?

Comment: @TheMathemagician define "more elements".

Comment: Isn't the number of elements well-defined for a finite set?

Comment: @TheMathemagician then you need to include the definition, and prove it from _that_ definition.

Comment: The cardinality of a finite set is the unique $n$ such that there exists a bijection between that set and the set of integers $1..N$.  You _could_ move from there. A set is finite iff such an $n$ exists.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239566/subset-of-a-finite-set-is-finite

Comment: @cesim: The last sentence in your proposed shorter proof presupposes that, whenever a set $S$ has an infinite subset, then $S$ itself is infinite.  Unfortunately, that's just a restatement of what you're trying to prove.

Comment: Why the votes to reopen?

Comment: @ChrisEagle: I vote to reopen. The duplicate question gives two proofs that are based on induction. The OP in the question wants to know "*Why do we need to use induction and such a long proof, instead could not we use basic proof by contradiction and let there exist an infinite subset[?]*"