# Set theory, property of addition of natural numbers in the cardinal way

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Consider the set of natural numbers $\mathbb N$. On this set we define an operation '+', as follows: for all $n,m \in \mathbb N$ we put $n+m$ to be the unique natural number $t \in \mathbb N$ such that there are $X,Y$ such that

$$ X \cap Y = \emptyset, \quad X \cup Y = t, \quad X \sim n, \quad Y \sim m.$$

This is called, for obvious reasons, the "cardinal definition" of addition on the natural numbers.

(You can assume that we already know (i.e. we've already proved) that there is such a natural number $t$, and moreover that this number is unique.)

Here '$X \sim n$' means that there is a bijection between $X$ and $n$.

I'm having a lot of trouble proving the following (quite elementary it seems) result:

**Theorem.** For all $m,n,k \in \mathbb N$ we have
$$ n < m \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad n + k < m + k.$$

(Here for any natural numbers $n,m$ we use the abbreviation $n<m$ for $n \in m$.)

Of course one would think that a good first approach would be to go by induction; I've tried it on $k$ but it didn't work out. Well..., it is clear that induction on $k$ 'works' assuming the fact that we already know that $n+(k+1) = (n+k) + 1$ for all natural numbers $n,k$. So it is sufficient to show the latter statement. I've found a proof for it, but ironically in the proof I (have to) use the above (unproved) theorem, namely the implication from left to right. So I'm basically stuck in a circularity.

I also tried several other things, without success.

*Comment.* You are not allowed to use any 'theorems' about the natural numbers, except for the most basic ones. For example, you may use that they form a linear order, but not much more. Also, at this point there is no such thing as an 'ordinal definition' of the '+' on the natural numbers.

Comment: What is your definition of the natural numbers?

Comment: The 'usual one', I guess: take any inductive set, which exists by the axiom of infinity. Then define $\mathbb N$ as the intersection of all inductive subsets of this set. (We can prove that this is well-defined etc. etc.)

Comment: it appears
$$
0=\emptyset
\\ 1=\{0\}
\\ 2=\{0,1\}
\\ \cdots
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that the natural numbers in your definition are transitive sets. So if $m\in m$ then $m\subseteq n$, and furthermore $m\neq n$, otherwise you would have $n\in n$ in contradiction to the axiom of regularity.

Use this fact to deduce that $m<n$ if and only if whenever $M,N$ are sets of cardinality $m,n$ respectively, there is an injection from $M$ into $N$, but there is no injection from $N$ into $M$. The latter may be easier to prove by using the pigeonhole principle (which you can prove independently by induction, see [1]).

First note that if $m=0$ then this follows from the above directly regardless to the value of $k$. So we may assume that $m\neq 0$.

We next prove by induction on $k$. For $k=0$ this is obvious. Assume that for $k-1$ it is true that $m+(k-1)<n+(k-1)$ whenever $m<n$.

Now suppose that $M\subsetneqq N$, and $K$ are sets of cardinality $m,n,k$ respectively, and $K$ is disjoint from $N$ (and so from $M$ as well). By the above it suffices to show that that there is no injection from $N\cup K$ into $M\cup K$ in order to show that $m+k<n+k$.

Suppose that there was an injection $g\colon N\cup K\to M\cup K$, restrict $g$ to $N$, since $M$ is a proper subset there has to be some $x\in N$ such that $g(x)\in K$, otherwise $g\upharpoonright N$ is an injection from $N$ into $M$. It follows that there exists some $u\in K$ such that $g(u)\in M$, otherwise $g\upharpoonright K$ would be an injection into $K\setminus\{g(x)\}$, which is impossible.

Define $f$ to be $(g\setminus\{\langle x,g(x)\rangle,\langle y,g(y)\rangle\})\cup\{\langle x,g(y)\rangle\}$. This is an injection from $N\cup K\setminus\{y\}$ into $M\cup K\setminus\{g(x)\}$. That is, an injection from a set of cardinality $n+(k-1)$ into a set of cardinality $m+(k-1)$. But the induction hypothesis tells us that this is a contradiction.

---

**More:**

1. [Subset of a finite set is finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239566/subset-of-a-finite-set-is-finite)

Answer (score 1):

We begin here by only assuming that the addition of finite cardinals is a well-defined associative binary operation on the the set $\mathbb N$ satisfying, for any $m,n \in \mathbb N$

$\tag 1 m + 0 = m \; \text{ and } \; m + (n + 1) =  (m+n) + 1$

(c.f. Appendix I of [Serge Lang's Undergraduate Algebra](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1pXoUPGwCetajA1Sk50cmNOaDA/edit)).

We also define $m \lt n$ to mean that there is a set of cardinality $m$ that can be non-surjectively injected into a set of cardinality $n$.

Proposition 1: For $m, n, k \in \mathbb N$, the statement $n \lt m$ is equivalent to $n + k \lt m+ k$.
Proof
We show that

$\tag 1 n + k \lt m+ k \text{ implies } m \lt n$

using induction on $k$. 
For $k = 0$ there is only one set with cardinality $0$, the empty set, and $\text{(1)}$ is true.
For the inductive step, assume that $\text{(1)}$ is true for an arbitrary $k$. We have

$\quad n + (k+1) = (n + k) + 1$

and

$\quad m + (k+1) = (m + k) + 1$

Now adding $1$ to two finite cardinals can be accomplished by finding a singleton set $\{\hat d\}$ disjoint from both of them. So we can extend our proper injection of the sets corresponding to $n + k$ and $m+k$ by mapping $\hat d \mapsto \hat d$. So we have another proper injection.

We leave the other direction to the reader. $\quad \blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

Let us define addition in a slightly different way. Let $n$ and $m$ be two natural numbers. Then we will define $n+m$ to be the unique element of $\mathbb{N}$ such that there exists sets $X_n, X_m$ such that if $X_n\sim n$ and $X_m\sim m$ and $X_n\cap X_m=\emptyset$, then $n+m\sim X_n\cup X_m$. We may also define $m\leq n$ if their is an injection of sets, $Y_n\hookrightarrow Y_m$ and $Y_n\sim n$ and $Y_m\sim m$. One may readily show that this is well defined given the following proposition.

**Proposition:** Let $X$ be any set such that $X\sim n$ and $X\sim m$. Then $n=m$.

Now to show your **Theorem**. If $m\leq n$, then their are is an injection ,$Y_m\hookrightarrow Y_n$. Now pick a set $X_k\sim k$ such that $X_k\cap Y_m=\emptyset$ and $X_k\cap Y_n=\emptyset$. Then we have $Y_m\cup X_k\hookrightarrow Y_n\cup X_k$ which proves the theorem.

**Edit** In the comments, the OP notes that we must show that the two definitions of $<$  is the same (the new one was implicitly defined in terns of  $\leq$). To this end let us first *assume that $<$ is transitive that is if $n\in m\in k$, then $n\in k$.* This means that $m=\{l:l<m\}$ and $k=\{l:l<k\}$. Then we get a map $m\hookrightarrow k$ which sends $l\mapsto l$.

**Proof of Transitivity**
Let us consider the set, $P=\{k\in\mathbb{N}:l\in n\in k\implies l\in k\}$. Certainly the empty set is in $P$ vacuously. Now suppose that $p\in P$ let us now show that $p\cup\{p\}\in P$, making $P$ an inductive set sitting inside if $\mathbb{N}$, amd therefore equal to $\mathbb{N}$. We must show that if we have a chain, $n\in k \in p\cup\{p\}$, then $k\in p\cup\{p\}$. If $n\in k\in p$ we are done since $p\in P$. On the other hand if $k\notin p$, then $k\in\{p\}$ which means that $k=p$. But then $n\in k=p\subset p\cup\{p\}$. Thus $P\subset\mathbb{N}$ is inductive and so $P=\mathbb{N}$, and so $,$ is transitive

Comment: Probably you mean that $n+m$ is the unique element in $\mathbb N$ such that **there are** $X_n$ and $X_m$ such that $X_n \sim n$, $X_m \sim m$, $X_n \cap X_m = \emptyset$ and $n + m \sim X_n \cup X_m$? Also, in your definition of $m \leq n$ I think you should say, $m \leq n$ if **there are** $Y_n, Y_m$ such that $Y_n \sim n$ and $Y_m \sim m$. I'm still looking at it, but for the rest it seems good, thanks. Also, I've already showed this proposition earlier, so it's no problem that it is left unproven here.

Comment: Using your 'new' definition of $\leq$, I think we should prove that it is well-defined. Namely, let us define $m < n$ iff ($m \leq n$ and $m \neq n$). We should prove that "our" $<$ is the same as the "old" $<$, which is $\in$. So we have to show that $$ ( m \neq n \mbox{ and } \exists Y_m \sim m, \; \exists Y_n \sim n \mbox{ and an injection } Y_m \hookrightarrow Y_n ) \quad \mbox{ iff } \quad m \in n. $$

Comment: Note that the proof of transitivity translates to other sets, $P$ which proves induction.