# Set theory: cardinality of a subset of a finite set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Suppose $A$ is a finite set of cardinality $n$. And Let $B$ be a subset of $A$ and the cardinality of $B$ equals $n$. Then $B=A$.

Many texts use this fact very frequently but it seems that they just take it for granted. How can I prove this rigorously? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $B \subseteq A$, we can partition $A = B \cup (A \setminus B)$. These sets are disjoint. Taking cardinalities, we see $n = n + \left|A \setminus B\right|$, which implies $|A \setminus B| = 0$, hence $A \setminus B = \emptyset$, so $A = B$.

Comment: In my opinion, it is obvious that B\A is empty since B is a subset of A. Maybe we gotta show A\B is empty...

Comment: Woops, $A \setminus B$ is what I meant.

Comment: God this is beautiful...thanks mark you're truly my savior. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome :) Glad it helped.

Comment: "These sets are disjoint." You mean $B$ and $A \setminus B$, right? (I'm sure that seems basic, but on my first reading, I had to stop and think about it quite a bit. Forgive me. I'm a lowly programmer who needed this result to make some code more efficient. ;) I don't do math with sets every day.)

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes. Stopping and thinking about things is pretty central to most reading of math :)

Comment: @Mark I'm a programmer. The holy grail for us is things so obvious and straightforward that you can read through without having to resolve ambiguities or fill in missing details. =p Even in my physics years, I did problems that way because I found I made mistakes too easily without flushing stuff out. My point was that while it might seem obvious to you, it isn't to others who aren't as focused in the field.

Comment: @Mark Well done. I have seen some needlessly complicated proofs of this result that relied on induction or properties of bijective functions, but this is pure elegance.

Comment: As the OP asks for a rigorous proof, I want to mention, that this proof strongly relies on two assumptions: the cardinality is unique and for two disjoint sets $A,B$ we have that $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|$. Both are statements you actually have to prove. I would rather suggest Asaf Karagila's answer.

Answer (score 7):

You have hit on a very subtle point, which many people can miss when they first run into this issue. Yes, we need to prove these things.

This is a consequence of the pigeonhole principle. If $B\subseteq A$, and $A$ is finite, then either $A=B$ or else there are no injective functions from $A$ into $B$; but if $|A|=|B|$ then by definition there is a bijection from $A$ into $B$.

So this, in turn, becomes a question as to how to prove the pigeonhole principle. The answer is by induction on the number of elements, and you can find a complete proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239566/subset-of-a-finite-set-is-finite).

Answer (score 2):

Let's prove the contrapositive statement.  Suppose that $A$ has a proper subset with the same cardinality as $A$ (in other words, $A$ is [Dedekind infinite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set).)  We will show that $A$ is infinite.

Take a proper subset $B$ of $A$ with the same cardinality as $A$.
  Then there is a bijection $f : A \to B$ and an element $a \in A \setminus B$.  Recursively define a function $h : \mathbb{N} \to A$ by

- $h(0) = a$
- $h(i+1) = f(h(i))$.

Using the fact that the function $f$ is injective and its range does not contain $a$, one can prove by induction on $j \in \mathbb{N}$ that the elements $h(0),\ldots,h(j)$ are distinct, so $h$ is an injection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$.
The existence of such an injection means that $\left|A\right| \ge \aleph_0$, so $A$ is infinite.

(There is a detail hiding here, namely the fact that there cannot be an injection from $\mathbb{N}$ to a finite set.  This can be proved by induction on the cardinality of the finite set by an argument similar to the one that Asaf mentions.)