# Does equal cardinality and one set being a subset of the other prove equality?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

I'm currently solving a quite specific problem and in the final step I made a statement that can be generalised such that:
$$((|A|=|B|)\wedge(A\subset B)) \implies (A=B)$$
Whilst this is clearly intuitively true for finite sets $A$ and $B$ and probably a safe statement for my purposes I was wondering if:

1. Is it mathematically sound to make such a statement for finite sets or should there be some further proof?
2. Is it the statement mathematically true in general including infinite sets?

Comment: Definitely not: Consider the even integers, a countably infinite subset of the integers.

Comment: For 2.: The existence of a proper subset of the same cardinality is often used as the definition of "infinite set".

Comment: Related, for the case of finite sets: [Set theory: cardinality of a subset of a finite set.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1304235/set-theory-cardinality-of-a-subset-of-a-finite-set)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Hint:** Use induction, and you can get a formal proof of this statement: Assume that $|A| = |B|=n$ and $A \subset B$. Since $|A| = |B|$, we note that there exists a bijection $f:A \to B$. Assume that $A \neq B$. Since $A \subset B \implies$ $\exists b \in B$ such that $b \not \in A$. But then, since $B$ is finite, we can show that $|A| < |B|$ (through induction) $\implies$ contradiction.
2. This is not true for infinite sets. Consider $B=\mathbb{N}$ and $A=\mathbb{N} - \{1\}$. Clearly, $A \subset B$, and one can show pretty easily that $|A| = |B|$. However, $A \neq B$.