# Proper subset of a finite set is finite

Tags: functions, solution-verification

I'm having trouble proving the following result without making circular arguments. I'm assuming no prior machinery for this problem other than the definition of finite (in bijection with $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ for some positive integer $n$ or empty) and of a subset.

> Let $B$ be a finite set and $A$ a proper subset. Then $|A| \leq |B|$ and $|A|$ is finite.

I'm going to assume $A$ is nonempty; I don't think this makes too big of a difference, because the result is immediately satisfied for the empty set. So there exists a bijection $f: B \to \{1, \ldots, n\}$ for some $n$. To somewhat get a map between $A$ and a set of positive integers, the most natural thing seems to be the inclusion $g: A \to B$, which is an injection. If I compose maps, I get an injection $f \circ g: A \to \{1, \ldots, n\}$. This in turn implies there is a bijection from $A$ to a proper subset of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$. I don't know what these elements are, but it seems I can assume, relabelling if necessary, that the image of $A$ is a list of elements of the form $\{1, \ldots, m\}$ for $m < n$. This sounds circular, however, but it seems "obvious" that if $A$ is a proper subset of $B$, then $g(f(A))$ has to be a proper subset of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$. I know that a map between two finite sets of the same size is injective if and only if it is surjective, so I'm wondering if I can in some way work this in there.

Comment: Depends on how you define finite, but it is easy to prove of $A$ is infinite and $A\subseteq B$ then $B$ is infinite. At least if you define "$X$ is infinite" iff there is a function $f:X\to X$ with $f$ injective but not bijective.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subset of a finite set is finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239566/subset-of-a-finite-set-is-finite) or one of [these many other posts about this FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Subset+of+a+finite+set)?

Answer (score 0):

You can assume WLOG that $B = \{ 1, \dots n \}$. This means $B$ is equipped with a natural order, namely the usual one, and hence $A$ inherits this order. Now enumerate the elements of $A$ from least to greatest: that is, take $a_1$ to be the least element, $a_2$ to be the least element not equal to $a_1$, and so forth. By induction it's clear that $a_k \ge k$, meaning this process terminates after at most $n$ steps, and so produces a bijection $k \leftrightarrow a_k$ between $\{ 1, \dots m \}$ and $A$ for some $m \le n$. (It's not necessary to assume that $A$ is a proper subset.)

Essentially the same argument works for infinite ordinals too.