# Is "Cardinality of a finite set is unique" $\iff$ "there exists a bjiection $f:A\to B \iff A=B$"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let be $|M|$ the cardinality of a finite set $M$. This means that there exists some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and a bijection $f:M\to\{1,\dots,n\}$.

Let's assume that $A\subseteq B$ and both are finite. I was wondering if the two statements

"*Cardinality of a finite set is unique*"

and

"*There exists a bjiection $f:A\to B \iff A=B$*"

are equivalent or if at least the first statement implies the second?

*Uniqueness of cardinality* means: if $f,g$ are two bijections with $f:A\to \{1,\dots,n\}$ and $g:A\to\{1,\dots,m\}$ then $m=n$.

---

I have gone through some proofs of the second statement, (e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/239567/579544) and it seems that the uniqueness of the cardinality is just a necessary condition but doesn't imply the second statement, does it?

(I hope that this question is not too vague, if so let me know it. )

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Cardinality, understood as equivalence class under "exists bijection" equivalence, is always unique, regardless of whether a set is finite or not. And your second statement is only true for empty set, unless you assume that $A\subseteq B$ a priori. So, are you asking when finite set is [Dedekind finite](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set) or vice versa? There is no simple answer to that, it depends on the underlying system of axioms.

Comment: @freakish, see my edit. I hope it's clear now :)

Comment: This kind of uniqueness always holds, the statement is just true. It cannot be otherwise. Regardless of whether set is finite or not.

Comment: What are A and B? Any finite sets? Two sets can be unequal, and still have a bijection between them, so the existence of a bijection $f: A \rightarrow B$ in almost no context implies $A = B$.

Comment: @freakish, It should be under the assumption of $A\subseteq B$. I put another edit.

Comment: @Philipp so what you are asking is whether "being finite" is equivalent to "being Dedekind finite", yes? Here "finite" means "equinumerous with some $\{1,\ldots,n\}$" while "Dedekind finite" means "if $A\subseteq B$ is equinumerous with $B$ then $A=B$". And as I said in my previous comment: that depends on the exact set theoretic axioms. You can read the wiki I linked in my previous comment.