# Show that cardinality of a finite set is unique

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> Let be $M$ a finite set, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f:M\to\{1,\dots,n\}$ a bijection. Then, $n$ is called the cardinality of $M$, denoted by $|M|=n$.
>
> Show that if there are two bijections $f,g$ such that $f:M\to\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $g:M\to\{1,\dots,m\}$, then $m=n$.

---

**My approach**:

I will prove the statement by induction on $n$:

**Base case** $n=1$:

We know that $\left(g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}\right):\{1\}\to\{1,\dots,m\}$ must be a bijection. So if $m>1$ it would be a contradiction. Hence, $n=1=m$.

**Induction hypothesis** with $n\in\mathbb{N}$:

If $f,g$ are two bijections with $f:M\to\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $g:M\to\{1,\dots,m\}$, then $m=n$.

**Induction step** $n\to n+1$:

We consider two bijections $f,g$ where $f:M\to\{1,\dots,n+1\}$ and $g:M\to\{1,\dots, m\}$. Then,
\begin{align*}
&f_1:M\setminus\{f^{-1}(n+1)\}\to\{1,\dots,n\},~f_1(k):=f(k)\text{ and}\\
&g_1:M\setminus\{g^{-1}(m)\}\to\{1,\dots,m-1\},~g_1(k):=g(k)
\end{align*}
must be two bijections as well. Otherwise we get a contradiction concerning the bijectivity of $f$ and $g$. We can apply the induction hypothesis which yields $n=m-1$ and finally $n+1=m$. So the induction step is complete and the statement holds for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

---

Is this correct?

PS: I know that there already exist some questions on this issue (e.g. [Subset of a finite set is finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/239566/579544)) but I would like to get some feedback on my approach.

Comment: This works, but I think to make it simpler you just need 2 facts:

(1) the inverse of a bijection is a bijection;

(2) the composition of 2 bijections is a bijection

Comment: @Paul, I noticed that my proof is wrong. I will post a new one.